# Pull Subscription is not working in Domain Network for Java based desktop service

Tags: java, spring-boot, networking, google-cloud-pubsub

We have one java based desktop service (Spring Boot Service) which has an implementation of google cloud pub/sub pull subscription. It is working fine without domain network however in domain network it is successfully subscribed to the subscription of Google Cloud Pub/Sub but unable to recieve messages after publishing message to the topic.

I am looking for the troubleshooting steps for domain network.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.